# Ajax webservices architecture

Tags: ajax, web-services

What is the difference between:

1. Using ajax to call web services directly and rendered the result into the html, and
2. Using ajax to call a local proxy and let the local proxy to call web services?

Comment: Keep your business rules in the web services and everything should be ok. But calling the web service directly you will get more coupled to the WS. Using a proxy, all the pages would be more coupled to the proxy, and there would be less impact in the WS changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally almost always use method 2.  This way you have more control over the service being called and can always substitute the proxy with a "mock" service to return pre-defined results for testing.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

the biggest difference is database transactions.  if your web service layer is orthogonal and fine-grained and common use-cases require multiple calls.  often you want to bundle more than one call into a single atomic database transaction: e. g. (debit account A, credit account B).

to do this you must use a local proxy because you cannot demarcate transactions on the client.